# How to cin values into a vector

Tags: c++, function, templates, vector, cin

I'm trying to ask the user to enter numbers that will be pushed into a vector,
then using a function call to count these numbers.

why is this not working?  I'm only able to count the first number.

```
template <typename T>
void write_vector(const vector<T>& V)
{
   cout << "The numbers in the vector are: " << endl;
  for(int i=0; i < V.size(); i++)
    cout << V[i] << " ";
}

int main()
{
  int input;
  vector<int> V;
  cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " << endl;
  cin >> input;
  V.push_back(input);
  write_vector(V);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my experience, cin only captures the first token in a string, so anything after a space gets cut off. If you really wanna use cin, either read in each variable separately, or have the user separate the values by a comma and then parse that. Or you can use the argv array in the main method.

Comment: Did you try using an additional variable?  Instead of using n for both the size and the temporary input.

Comment: You should explain what's not working here.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes BenjaminLindley I agree with you guys, however I thought the OP spent some time already, and can get the answer. Of course, your approach is much better.

Answer (score 49):

As is, you're only reading in a single integer and pushing it into your vector. Since you probably want to store several integers, you need a loop. E.g., replace

```
cin >> input;
V.push_back(input);
```

with

```
while (cin >> input)
    V.push_back(input);
```

What this does is continually pull in ints from cin for as long as there is input to grab; the loop continues until cin finds EOF or tries to input a non-integer value. The alternative is to use a sentinel value, though this prevents you from actually inputting that value. Ex:

```
while ((cin >> input) && input != 9999)
    V.push_back(input);
```

will read until you try to input 9999 (or any of the other states that render cin invalid), at which point the loop will terminate.

Comment: operator void* does not return NULL for EOF, so the while (cin >> input) only aborts for invalid input, but not EOF.

Comment: Using an istream in a condition, e.g. while (cin >> input) evaluates the stream (or, more precisely in this case, the reference to the stream returned by operator>>) by checking its state, which is made invalid when the stream tries to read in EOF and therefore is evaluated as false.

Comment: Hitting EOF sets both eofbit and failbit. I apparently had some misunderstanding about the evaluation of streams as conditions, though, which your comments have lead me to investigate and clear up, so thanks!

Answer (score 22):

You need a loop for that. So do this:

```
while (cin >> input) //enter any non-integer to end the loop!
{
   V.push_back(input);
}
```

Or use this idiomatic version:

```
#include <iterator> //for std::istream_iterator 

std::istream_iterator<int> begin(std::cin), end;
std::vector<int> v(begin, end);
write_vector(v);
```

You could also improve your `write_vector` as:

```
 #include <algorithm> //for std::copy

template <typename T>
void write_vector(const vector<T>& v)
{
   cout << "The numbers in the vector are: " << endl;
   std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: Now its stuck in a continuous loop of asking for numbers.

Comment: @Sean: No. Enter any non-integer to end the loop!

Comment: if i ask the user to enter a certain amount of inputs how could i stop it after that many?

Comment: @Sean `for(int i = 0; i < inputcount; ++i) { // do your stuff here }`

Comment: @Sean: Just ask him to enter ANY non-integer to end to the loop. For example, it could be anthing. `A`, `a`, `jikhjik`, `1.29`. It should be non-integer. Why don't you experiment, and see how it works?

Comment: @Nawaz: It works as you say, but how does that work? `end` is uninitialised; do `istream_iterator`s default construct to some error state which is matched by the other iterator when there is bad input? Seems kinda dodgy to me.

Comment: @Mozza314: No. `end` is not uninitialized, it is class, to the default constructor gets called which initialized it.

Answer (score 21):

Other answers would have you disallow a particular number, or tell the user to enter something non-numeric in order to terminate input. Perhaps a better solution is to use `std::getline()` to read a *line* of input, then use `std::istringstream` to read all of the numbers from that line into the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::string line;
    int number;
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    std::cout << "Enter numbers separated by spaces: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream stream(line);
    while (stream >> number)
        numbers.push_back(number);

    write_vector(numbers);

}
```

Also, your `write_vector()` implementation can be replaced with a more idiomatic call to the `std::copy()` algorithm to copy the elements to an `std::ostream_iterator` to `std::cout`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template<class T>
void write_vector(const std::vector<T>& vector) {
    std::cout << "Numbers you entered: ";
    std::copy(vector.begin(), vector.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

You can also use `std::copy()` and a couple of handy iterators to get the values into the vector without an explicit loop:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(stream),
    std::istream_iterator<int>(),
    std::back_inserter(numbers));
```

But that’s probably overkill.

Comment: The code is what i need , but it does not input the first number with cin . So if the user enters 2 3 5 6 7 , number starts from 3 in the while loop . How do i fix that ?

Answer (score 14):

you have 2 options:

If you know the size of vector will be (in your case/example it's seems you know it):

```
vector<int> V(size)
for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
    cin>>V[i];
 }
```

if you don't and you can't get it in you'r program flow then:

```
int helper;
while(cin>>helper){
    V.push_back(helper);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 10):

If you know the size of the vector you can do it like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n);
    for (auto &it : v) {
        cin >> it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

*One-liner* to read a **fixed** amount of numbers into a vector (C++11):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    const std::size_t LIMIT{5};
    std::vector<int> collection;

    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(collection), LIMIT,
        []()
        {
            return *(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin));
        }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: creating an iterator just to fetch single value? Crappy solution. `std::copy_n` is better in this case.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the size use this

**No temporary variable used just to store user input**

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    int n;//input size
    cin >> n;
    vector<int>a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

//to verify output user input printed below

    for (auto x : a) {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a second integer.

```
int i,n;
vector<int> V;
cout << "Enter the amount of numbers you want to evaluate: ";
cin >> i;
cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " << endl;
while (V.size() < i && cin >> n){
  V.push_back(n);
}
write_vector(V);
return 0;
```

Comment: Works perfect except i would prefer for the program to cin after the ith number instead of i+1.  Would i have to use a differrent type of loop for that?

Comment: By cin after the ith number instead of i+1, did you mean take one fewer input value than this? `while (cin >> n && V.size() < i-1)` will do that. If you want to take one more instead of one less, `i+1` instead. Don't use the `++` or `--` operators here, those will change the value of `i`.

Comment: i mean by using this say i enter 3 for the amount of numbers to be evaluated.  The program wont run until i have entered the fourth number and then it will cout the correct amount being 3.  Is there a way to start the program after entering the third number.

Comment: `while (V.size() < i && cin >> n)`

Comment: No problem. Take a few minutes to look over your questions and accept the answers that you judge most complete - click the check mark outline and it will fill in.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to read in more numbers, not only one.
For this, you need a loop

```
int main()
{
  int input = 0;
  while(input != -1){
    vector<int> V;
    cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    V.push_back(input);
    write_vector(V);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note, with this version, it is not possible to add the number -1 as it is the "end signal".
Type numbers as long as you like, it will be aborted when you type -1.

Answer (score 3):

cin is delimited on space, so if you try to cin "1 2 3 4 5" into a single integer, your only going to be assigning 1 to the integer, a better option is to wrap your input and push_back in a loop, and have it test for a sentinel value, and on that sentinel value, call your write function. such as

```
int input;
cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated, and 10000 to quit: " << endl;
while(input != 10000) {
    cin >> input;
   V.push_back(input);
}
write_vector(V);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this with the help of **for loop**
->Ask on runtime from a user  (*how many inputs he want to enter*) and the treat same like arrays.

```
int main() {
        int sizz,input;
        std::vector<int> vc1;

        cout<< "How many Numbers you want to enter : ";
        cin >> sizz;
        cout << "Input Data : " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizz; i++) {//for taking input form the user
            cin >> input;
            vc1.push_back(input);
        }
        cout << "print data of vector : " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizz; i++) {
            cout << vc1[i] << endl;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string>V;
    int num;
    cin>>num;
    string input;
    while (cin>>input && num != 0) //enter any non-integer to end the loop!
{
    //cin>>input;
   V.push_back(input);
   num--;
   if(num==0)
   {
   vector<string>::iterator it;
    for(it=V.begin();it!=V.end();it++)
        cout<<*it<<endl;
   };

}
return 0;

};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    string line,t;
    getline(cin,line);
    istringstream iss(line);
    while(iss>>t)
        v.push_back(t);

    vector<string>::iterator it;
    for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please describe what your code does and modify it so it matches the code of the question

Answer (score 1):

In this case your `while` loop will look like

```
int i = 0;
int a = 0;
while (i < n){
  cin >> a;
  V.push_back(a);
  ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>The initial `size()` of `V` will be 0, while int n contains any random value because you don't initialize it.</s>

`V.size() < n` is probably false.

Silly me missed the `"Enter the amount of numbers you want to evaluate: "`

If you enter a `n` that's smaller than `V.size()` at that time, the loop will terminate.

Comment: `n` is initialized with `cin >> n`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another variable.

```
int temp;
while (cin >> temp && V.size() < n){
    V.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to change one `n` :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: What do you mean?  `V.size() < n`?  That's intentional.

Comment: Shouldn't conditions be switched? If `n == 0` you will keep waiting.

Comment: I fixed it. You had `V.push_back(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int x,n;
cin>>x;
vector<int> v;

cout<<"Enter numbers:\n";

for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
 {
  cin>>n;
  v.push_back(n);
 }


//displaying vector contents

 for(int p : v)
 cout<<p<<" ";
}
```

A simple way to take input in vector.

Answer (score 1):

These were two methods I tried. Both are fine to use.

```
int main() {
       
        int size,temp;
        cin>>size;
        vector<int> ar(size);
    //method 1 
      for(auto i=0;i<size;i++)
          {   cin>>temp;
              ar.insert(ar.begin()+i,temp);
          }
          for (auto i:ar) 
            cout <<i<<" "; 
            
     //method 2
     for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
     {
        cin>>ar[i];
     }
     
     for (auto i:ar) 
            cout <<i<<" "; 
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

would be easier if you specify the size of vector by taking an input :

```
int main()
{
  int input,n;
  vector<int> V;
  cout<<"Enter the number of inputs: ";
  cin>>n;
  cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " << endl;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
  cin >> input;
  V.push_back(input);
  }
  write_vector(V);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and this is how I did it. Using &modifying your code appropriately:

```
   int main()
   {
   int input;
   vector<int> V;
   cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " 
   << '\n' << "type "done" & keyboard Enter to stop entry" 
   <<   '\n';
   while ( (cin >> input) && input != "done") {
   V.push_back(input);
    }
   write_vector(V);
   return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "do you like to enter the sem 2 score "<<endl;
cin >> sem2;

if (sem2 == 'Y' || sem2 == 'y')
{
    cout << "enter your subject count ";
    cin >> subjectcount;
    cout << " enter your scores :";
    for (int i = 0; i < subjectcount; i++)
    {
        double  ip;
        cout << (i+1) << " st score ";
        cin >> ip;
        sem2score.push_back(ip);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract numbers by this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int aux;
    char c='\n';
    char a;

    while(scanf("%d", &aux))
    {
        cout<<aux<<endl;
        if(scanf("%c",&a) && a==c)
            break;  
    }
    return 0;
}
```