How to take input from the user to initialize vector of vectors in C++?
Here's my piece of code where I'm trying to take input from the for the 2D vector, however I'm getting segmentation fault when I'm trying to enter the input. I'm trying to use insert member function instead of push_back.
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
vector< vector<int> > v;
int rowsa=2;
int colsa=2;
int temp=0;

// Iterator
vector< vector<int>> :: iterator iter=v.begin();
vector<int> :: iterator it;

cout<<"Enter the matrix values row wise: "<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<rowsa; i++)
{
    it=v[i].begin();
    for(int j=0; j<colsa; j++)
    {
        cin>>temp;
        v[i].insert(it+j, temp);
    }
}

cout<<"Entered matrix is: "<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<rowsa;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<colsa;j++)
    {
        cout<<v[i][j]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

return 0;
}


The vector v is empty, so any indexing into it will be out of bounds. And as the vectors are empty, the begin() function will return the end() iterator. I suggest you tead the inner vector as a new (but temporary vector) and then push it into the outer vector v.

Why are you using insert instead of push_back? This questions seems like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8377660/ unless use of insert is somehow important here.

the program does not work because the vector is uninitiated. This causes an undefined behavior, which messes up the program. I would also recommend not using .insert() member function but because you said you wanted to use it, here is my approach using .insert() member function:
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using std::vector, std::cout, std::cin;

int main() {
    int row_size=2;
    int col_size=2;
    vector<vector<int>> v (row_size, vector<int> (col_size));
    int temp=0;

    cout << "Enter the matrix values row wise: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < row_size; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col_size; ++j){
            cin >> temp;
            v[i].insert(v[i].end(), temp);
            v[i].erase(v[i].begin());
        }
    }

    cout<<"Entered matrix is: \n";
    for (vector<int> row : v) {
        for (int column : row) {
            cout << column << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

(You could also take the row and column size from the user so they can create a custom 2D vector)
